# Bitcoin core node is not starting after -prune is applied in bitcoin.config file

Tags: bitcoin-core, pruning

I have a bitcoin core full node version 0.17.1 running on my machine. I want to enable prune on the node to save space on the disk. When I apply -prune=15000 in bitcoin.config file and restart bitcoin core GUI, it shows -txindex is incompatible with prune. So I want to start my node with prune enabled. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 2):

By pruning the blockchain you:

> Reduce storage requirements by enabling pruning (deleting) of old
>          blocks. This allows the pruneblockchain RPC to be called to
>          delete specific blocks, and enables automatic pruning of old
>          blocks if a target size in MiB is provided. This mode is
>          incompatible with -txindex and -rescan. Warning: Reverting this
>          setting requires re-downloading the entire blockchain. (default:
>          0 = disable pruning blocks, 1 = allow manual pruning via RPC,
>   =550 = automatically prune block files to stay under the
>          specified target size in MiB)

So, -txindex cannot be enabled when the blockchain in pruned

Comment: I tried to update property of .exe file like "C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -prune=150000 -reindex, and started bitcoin core application on windows server 2012. But still I am getting error that Prune mode is incompatible with -txindex.

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. It seems txindex cannot run together with prune. This is the help message from bitcoind

Comment: I don't want to run -txindex, what I want is to run Bitcoin core wallet after prune is enabled. So is there any way to start node after we specify prune?

Comment: Check your bitcoin.conf file. There is a high likelihood that you have -txindex=1 over there which is why it is popping out the error.